# .htaccess change file name on link clicked

Tags: .htaccess

this is not working, which is supposed to be the easy part

```
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
 RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /rent\.php 
 #RewriteRule . RentCar/ [R=301,L]
 RewriteRule ^RentCar/$ rent.php[L]
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /rent 
 RewriteRule ^RentCar/$ rent[L]
```

---

While more compliacted parts  which are BEFORE this code work

```
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /rent2\.php\?r=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
  RewriteRule . CarRental/%1/? [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /rent2\.php\?r=([^&\s]+)&w=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
  RewriteRule . CarRental/%1/%2/? [R=301,L]

  RewriteRule ^CarRental/([^/]+)/$ rent2.php?r=$1 [L]
  RewriteRule ^CarRental/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ rent2.php?r=$1&w=$2 [L]
```

Comment: First part takes to: http://www.lebmotors.com/new/rent 
While second successfully takes to:
http://www.lebmotors.com/new/CarRental/moto/Bike/

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: Thank You a Lot, if worked, I am getting better at this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was resolved after some focus:

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /rent.php\s [NC]
   RewriteRule . RentACar/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^RentACar/$ rent.php [L]

Now Working

http://www.lebmotors.com/new/RentACar/